# Centre of a matrix ring are $ \operatorname{diag}\{ a, a, ..., a \} $ with $ a\in Z(R) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $Z(M_n(R))$ consist of $ \operatorname{diag}\{ a, a, ..., a \} $ with $ a\in Z(R) $

Comment: We do not like taking orders. Instead, please indicate how you came across this problem; why it interests you; what you already know about it, and about the concepts mentioned in it; how far you got in your efforts to solve it; where you got stuck; and so on, and so on. Engage with us, so we can engage with you.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 24):

Here are some things to think about which should put you in the right direction.

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})\in Z(M_n(R))$. Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$, and all other entries are $0$. Then the equations
$$
E_{ii}A=AE_{ii}
$$
for $1\leq i\leq n$ implies that $A$ is necessarily diagonal. (Why?) Furthermore,
$$
AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A
$$
for $1\leq i,j\leq n$ implies that $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$ for all $i$ and $j$. (Why?) Hence $A=aI_n$ for some $a\in R$. But notice that
$$
aI_n(bI_n)=bI_n(aI_n),\quad \forall b\in R
$$
implies that $a\in Z(R)$.

Comment: This answer assumes that $R$ contains 1, which we are not given.

Comment: Fair point. I guess if it's just a rng the claim isn't always true. One could take $R$ the rng of square zero, then $M_n(R)$ also has zero multiplication, so is commutative. But then the center is not just the diagonal matrices.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the claim was true but merely a bit more tedious to prove, but I see now you're right, we must have 1.

Comment: I see the argument with $E_{ii}$, but not yet the one with $E_{ij}$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman You can use the formula for finding the entries of a product of matrices. Let $B=AE_{ij}$. Then the $(k,l)$ entry of $B$ is $b_{kl}=\sum_{s=1}^na_{ks}e_{sl}=a_{kk}e_{kl}$ since $A$ is diagonal. In particular, when $k=i$ and $l=j$, one concludes $b_{ij}=a_{ii}e_{ij}=a_{ii}$. Similarly, since $B=E_{ij}A$, the same argument shows that $b_{ij}=a_{jj}$, so $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$.